# Fatal error: Class 'Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento, admin

I'm getting an error in the admin page when I try to login, it was working fine and I would like to know if you can please help find out what may be causing the error and how to fix it. The error is:

Fatal error: Class 'Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data' not found in /home/site/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

The admin page is only showing the header and the error line code, the search box but the search box is not giving any results neither. However, the front of the store is working find, no issues in front. Please help, thank you

Best Regards,

Jenny

Comment: I acknowledge what xray said: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64467/24603

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This looks like an extension has been installed but not completely. The error is because Magento is trying to find the file `Magpleasure_Filesystem_Helper_Data` which I guess will either be under code base local or community `app/code/local/Magpleasure/Filesystem/Helper/Data.php` but the file is not there.

I would suggest reinstalling the extension either by magento connect or locally and deploy to your system and if you are still having issues contacting the developer directly may be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help, it is working now, it was a faulty extension which was uninstalled buut I guess was uninstalled properly.

Comment: This might have been correct before the widespread deployment of Magento attacks against servers that weren't patched with SUPEE-5394, but as of now it's lacking in context.

Answer (score 3):

99% that you were hacked and that you didn't apply the two patches which were released by magento some weeks ago...

I have seen that issue 1 day ago at a client side of mine and they also didn't apply the patch. 
check also this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64461/error-logging-in-the-admin-panel-fatal-error-class-magpleasure-filesystem-help

Comment: xray, did you happen to archive the files that you discovered were compromised?  We started an open source project to help classify and identify known signatures at https://github.com/comitdevelopers/magento-security-toolkit  You can participate yourself if you'd like or we're just happy to take whatever sigs you want to share and add them to our growing database.

Answer (score 1):

It also happened to me. Did not install the security patches.

Follow the steps from this post:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64461/error-logging-in-the-admin-panel-fatal-error-class-magpleasure-filesystem-help

```
Remove all files: app/code/community/Magpleasure/Filesystem/
Clear your cache, login should be possible now.
Check for new "Admin Users"
Patch your System with SUPEE-5344!
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to my site AGAIN, even after removing the magepleasure files, and then installing the 2 security patches.

I looked in the community and local folders as noted above in the way that I fixed this the first time around. This time there was one called Ma2.

I deleted the files from both places and deleted the cache folder contents on the server. I was then able to get the backend again. There was another unauthorized user, deleted it.

There is a remaining problem though. Anybody know where to look to fully delete the problem?

Comment: Murphy, I got a few other developers who have been doing a lot of Magento remediation work lately to pool our experience and we've started the Magento Security Toolkit OSS Project: https://github.com/comitdevelopers/magento-security-toolkit

We had planned to release the first of the n98-magerun extensions this week, but with the release of SUPEE-6286 we've pushed it back to the weekend.  You can review the signatures.md file for an explanation of what sigs have been discovered and how to remove them  We've located about 20 or so so it shouldn't long to finish.  Add your own and submit a PR!

Answer (score 1):

This is Compiler Error edit index.php, there just comment out following lines

1. $compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php'; if
   (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
       include $compilerConfig; }

it will fix now..